# Wecoomerce custom query to filter products loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to filter my products when user selects order by option on my website. I need to show produtcs ordered by the user option and if _sku equals to 'NONE' it need to go to the end of the list of the products.

For example:
 My produtcs:

```
 _sku title
 1     Aprodu
 2     Dprodu
 NONE  Bprodu
 3     Cprodu
 NONE  Eprodu
```

So if the user selects to order by title. The products will have to get this result:

```
  1     Aprodu
  3     Cprodu
  2     Dprodu
  NONE  Bprodu
  NONE  Eprodu
```

The first three items are ordered by title is this case and if _sku equals 'NONE' it will be going to the end of the list.

I tried:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'filter_case' );

function filter_case($orderby = '') {
  $orderby .= 'CASE WHEN posts._sku = 'NONE' THEN 0';
  return $orderby;
}
```